# Why does CrystalDiskInfo show "B1 Vendor Specific" as a bad disk health indicator?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, smart, crystaldiskinfo

I have bad performance when processing large files and I ran CrystalDiskInfo and it shows disk health status as "bad" with row ID=B1 and "Vendor Specific" marked in red.

I tried looking at S.M.A.R.T attributes lists but nowhere does it list "B1" specifically.

Can anyone explain what is this? (image below). I'm assuming it's wear level and it's currently at 1 with 10 being the threshold...

[image: CrystalDiskInfo]

Comment: Because the normalized value is less than the threshold I guess.

Comment: Oh so it's actually supposed to be 10 at least... Any idea what that value represents though?

Comment: I got some incorrect information from a colleague but upon review of the relevant docs I could not find any reference to this. I have now contacted Micron technical support and will update here once they reply hopefully with a proper answer.

Comment: Micron support say it's an OEM disk for Dell and need to check with Dell...